# Google Chrome hosted app: loading a content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've developed a simple Chrome hosted app and now I would like to integrate some content scripts in it but according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/articles/apps_vs_extensions), it seems that this kind of app can't integrate content scripts.

Should I develop 2 separate apps? The first which is just the hosted app, adding an icon to the dashboard and letting users launching my web app in seconds and a second with the content scripts or is their a way to achieve that with one app?

Thanks for your help.